# Existing (possibly everyday) technologies that must account for electromagnetic momentum?

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, technology, big-list

Can anyone suggest existing technologies that must account for electromagnetic momentum? I believe one example to be [confinement in nuclear fusion](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node90.html); but momentum there appears in an averaged form, as pressure.

Just to give an idea of what I mean with "existing technologies": general-relativistic time dilation has to be [concretely taken into account](https://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/pogge.1/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html) in any phone's GPS.

*(Edit: many excellent answers have been given, it's really difficult and partly meaningless to choose one as "the" answer! I chose JEB's one mostly because it is about a macroscopic effect and about a directed form of electromagnetic momentum, rather than more "averaged" forms closer to electromagnetic pressure.)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

uh....solar sails?

Radiation pressure is also important in precision satellite GNC. It affects orbits, and to some degree, pointing.

And of course, any asteroid deflection technology relying on the Yarkovsky Effect.

Any mission to intercept a comet...needs to know where the tail(s) are going to be.

Comment: A set of brilliant suggestions! Please feel free to add any references, if you think there are any must-read ones :)

Comment: TESS has to perform "momentum dumps" every few days to compensate for torque due to light pressure. https://spaceflight101.com/tess/tess-spacecraft/ https://archive.stsci.edu/files/live/sites/mast/files/home/missions-and-data/active-missions/tess/_documents/TESS_Instrument_Handbook_v0.1.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Laser cooling techniques do rely on the fact that the absorption and emission of photons is accompanied by a transfer of momentum from the absorbed photon to the electron (and from there to the atom).

Comment: This is brilliant too! Please feel free to add any must-read references, if you think of any special ones (I know nothing about laser cooling).

Comment: @pglpm [Atomic fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_fountain) clocks, like NIST-F2, use clouds of laser-cooled atoms, and the techniques for manpulating those clouds are related to the laser tweezers mentioned in another answer. Several atomic fountains are important contributors to the global atomic clock network which is the basis of the [TAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time) time scale that the UTC time scale is based on.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if there's a particular mass scale you're interested in, but any technology that uses EM radiation to communicate is going to rely on momentum from those waves to accomplish anything.

Just like the railway car in the example you linked, an electron that appears to spontaneously move in one direction after an incoming radio wave must have gotten its momentum from the wave, otherwise the conservation of momentum would be violated.

Comment: That's brilliant :) Larger mass scales would be cool, but this example is really fundamental. Please let me wait in choosing this as the answer, to invite more answers. Cheers!

Comment: Similarly: camera sensors, spectrometry, even lighting.

Comment: The electrons move in a direction that is **perpendicular** to the momentum of the light though. The classical treatment of transmitters and receivers makes no use of the momentum carried by light at all, only the electric fields and power/Poynting vector are important.

Comment: @ProfRob pool balls can also carry momentum in a direction **perpendicular** to the momentum they impart. This isn't a foreign concept.

Comment: That's a heck of a trick shot if you can cut a pool ball at 90 degrees to the cue ball.

Answer (score 6):

[Optical tweezers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_tweezers) are quite a well-developed technology and use the force generated when you divert laser light through a dielectric object to manipulate small objects. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_tweezers#Ray_optics for a description of how the light exerts a force on the particle by changing its momentum (direction).

Comment: Great suggestion!

Comment: I don't think that this a good example. The forces on the dielectric are in general explained without making use of any momentum transfer from the light field to the object, and I can't think of an easy way of explaining the effect in this framework at the moment.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp how do you explain the force on something caused by light without making use of the fact it has momentum?

Comment: @ProfRob because of the AC-Stark effect, the object has less energy, depending on the field strength --> there must be a force along the gradient of the field strength. I don't need to even know that the EM-Field has momentum to do this, let alone that it is transfered. 
On the contrary, describing the optical tweezer in terms of the momentum transfer will become ugly at best. It is not even clear in what way the beam loses momentum, and in what portions exactly.
It would be fair to say that I am nitpicky, however, but the above reasoning is where I'm coming from.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp the beam doesn;t "lose momentum", it changes momentum. Force is $dp/dt$ where $p$ is a vector quantity. All explanations that I have seen of optical tweezers discuss this in terms of the force exerted on the particle/cell as a result of the changing momentum of the light beam accompanied by a Newton's third law back-reaction on the particle. In order to trap the particle then yes, the beam has to be shaped to have a particular intensity profile, but the whole technique works because light has momentum.e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_tweezers#Ray_optics

Comment: I wasn't aware of those explanations (besides the AC-Stark effect) explanation, but they certainly qualify. Sorry for bothering.